# Parse and reuse a WP Rest object that was stored in a text file with var_export

Tags: php

I have a WP REST object stored in a file with `file_put_contents( ABSPATH . '/wp-content/data_' . time() . '_export.txt', var_export( $data, true ) );`

Now I want to parse and reuse a specific param of that object...

The stored .txt file has a content like this:

```
WP_REST_Request::__set_state(array(
   'method' => 'POST',
   'params' => 
  array (
    'URL' => 
    array (
    ),
    'GET' => 
    array (
      'ps' => '6HqGAhPRd9Wj',
    ),
    'POST' => 
    array (
    ),
    'FILES' => 
    array (
    ),
    'JSON' => 
    array (
      'event_type' => 'order_updated',
      'event_time' => '2023-06-16T15:44:14',
      'order' => 
      'changes' => 
      array (
        'state' => 
        array (
          'old' => 'open',
          'new' => 'accepted',
        ),
        'pickup_window' => 
        array (
          'old' => NULL,
          'new' => 
          array (
            'from' => '2023-06-19T15:00:00',
            'to' => '2023-06-19T18:00:00',
          ),
        ),
        'number_of_parcels' => 
        array (
          'old' => NULL,
          'new' => 1,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'defaults' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
   'body' => '',
   'parsed_json' => true,
   'parsed_body' => false,
))
```

But how do I do this? I've seen others suggesting like this: `$content = include 'path/to/file';` or

```
   $content = file_get_contents( 'path/to/file' );
   eval( '$somevar = ' . $content.';' );
```

But non of these work.

Am I doing something wrong?